# UIFont fontName for Bold Lucida Grande

Tags: ios, uikit, uifont

I couldn't find the name system name of the Lucida Grande bold font, and I need to use it in [UIFont fontWithName:size:]. Can anybody give me the exact name? couldn't find it on internet lists.
Tnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That font, like many other, is not available for use in iOS. To get the list of the available fonts, use:

```
    NSArray *familyNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont familyNames]];
    NSArray *fontNames;
    NSInteger indFamily, indFont;
    for (indFamily=0; indFamily<[familyNames count]; ++indFamily)
    {
        NSLog(@"Family name: %@", [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]);
        fontNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:
                     [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:
                      [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]]];
        for (indFont=0; indFont<[fontNames count]; ++indFont)
        {
            NSLog(@"    Font name: %@", [fontNames objectAtIndex:indFont]);
        }
        [fontNames release];
    }
    [familyNames release];
```

http://ajnaware.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/list-of-fonts-available-on-the-iphone/

Also note that the font list can change with iOS updates.

Comment: Ah, then why would they let me choose it in Interface builder without informing me its not there? >.> Tnx anyways.

Comment: @Niv: That font dialog box is just a list of all installed fonts on the local computer. It does not mean that all of those fonts are included in iOS.

Comment: I realize that, but you would've expected he'd realize your developing for iOs, and therefor he should display only the fonts available there. what use do I have of other fonts? oh well :)

Comment: http://iosfonts.com also has a nice overview and includes the font name if I am not mistaking.

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't find it because its not available on the system. You'll need to pick a different font.